# BarChart3d not working as expected

Tags: charts

I have multiple barcharts which I want to display in a single plot, one chart behind the next. I found I can do this with BarChart3D. But it's not working properly. I have the following data:

```
data = {{10, 26, 7, 60}, {31, 29, 7, 42}, {9, 38, 6, 61}, {41, 18, 15,
    21}, {51, 20, 24, 12}, {31, 11, 26, 22}, {32, 22, 21, 13}}
```

Each list should be a BarChart. But when I plot it using

```
BarChart3D[data, ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

I do not get seven bar charts, each with 4 bars behind each other, but 4 bar charts each with 7 bars. So I thought I simply transpose the list, using:

```
BarChart3D[Transpose@data, ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

But I get exactly the same result ... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post screenshots? When I evaluate the same thing in my Mathematica 11.1.1 (Windows), I feel like one of them is giving me what you're after: https://puu.sh/vZ4Gv/94a65e040e.png

Comment: Honestly ... after looking at your images, I tried it again. I get the impression, I rotated the results to quickly, and, of course, when you rotate by 90º, they looks similar. I most probably got confused by that. Apologies. But your pics definitely helped me spot my mistake!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad you were able to figure it out